# Whats wrong with my Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of javascript and php:

```
function change(){

var heading = "<?= $heading ?>";
var description = "<?= $description ?>";
var valid = "<?= $valid ?>";
var background = "<?= $background ?>";
alert("hi");
    switch(background){
        case 1:
        document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "(url"img/bg1.jpg")";
        break;

        case 2:

        break;

        case 3:

        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

If I remove the case 1, the line: `document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "(url"img/bg1.jpg")";` the function will work, I'll get the hi alert. But if its in there it doesn't work at all. But I've used that line of code before and its worked, why does it cause this script to stop working?

TIA

Comment: The code highlighting above should lead you to the exact spot with the problem (look for where the colors of the text seem to change unusually). If you're going to do `"this "is" text"` (note the `"` in the sentence), you will need to escape the `"` that are inside the statement, ie, `"this \"is\" text"`, or switch to single quotes, ie, `"this 'is' text"`.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing that line with:

```
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('img/bg1.jpg')";
```

Comment: Ah yes, thats the trick. I tried a few combinations of changing the marks but not that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`case 1` should be as below

```
case 1:
    document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url("img/bg1.jpg")";
    break;
```

Comment: The `url()` needs to be quoted too: http://jsfiddle.net/tXKVq/ and http://jsfiddle.net/tXKVq/1/.